# HMMLearn: Too Many Values to Unpack

Tags: python, hmmlearn

I'm trying to use `hmmlearn` to get the most likely hidden state sequence from a Hidden Markov Model, given start probabilities, transition probabilities, and emission probabilities.

I have two hidden states and four possible emission values, so I'm doing this:

```
num_states = 2
num_observations = 4
start_probs = np.array([0.2, 0.8])
trans_probs = np.array([[0.75, 0.25], [0.1, 0.9]])
emission_probs = np.array([[0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3], [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1]])

model = hmm.MultinomialHMM(n_components=num_states)
model.startprob_ = start_probs
model.transmat_ = trans_probs
model.emissionprob_ = emission_probs

seq = np.array([[3, 3, 2, 2]]).T

model.fit(seq)
log_prob, state_seq = model.decode(seq)
```

My stack trace points to the `decode` call and throws this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I thought `decode` (looking at the docs) returns a log probability and the state sequence, so I'm confused.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The call `model.fit(seq)` requires `seq` to be a list of lists, as you correctly set it up like this.
However, `model.decode(seq)` requires seq to only be a list, not a list of lists. Thus,

```
model.fit([[3, 3, 2, 2]])
log_prob, state_seq = model.decode([3, 3, 2, 2])
```

should work without throwing an error.
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34379911/how-to-run-hidden-markov-models-in-python-with-hmmlearn).

The error `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` is thrown from a function called by a function called by a function... inside `decode`. So, the error does not mean that the number of returned objects of `decode` was wrong, but from `framelogprob.shape` somewhere inside the `base.py`. A more meaningful error message would make life easier here.
I had the same issue and it drove me crazy. Hope my post helps somebody.